# C# Faster Stack Trace

Tags: c#, performance, stack-trace

I need to be able to get a list of all of the methods that have been called up to a point. Unfortunately I'm unable to use the [CallerInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information) attributes so that pretty much just leaves me the StackTrace.

I know that the StackTrace is not great for performance so I was hoping there were other alternatives out there can do this and not be so performance heavy. I found this article (https://ayende.com/blog/3879/reducing-the-cost-of-getting-a-stack-trace) that has an example of how to speed up the Stack Trace but I'm not sure how to really get the method names using that. Here's what I have so far:

```
void Main()
{
   var result = getTheStackTrace.Invoke();
}

private Func<object> getTheStackTrace;

public void FastStack()
{
    var stackFrameHelperType = typeof(object).Assembly.GetType("System.Diagnostics.StackFrameHelper");
    var GetStackFramesInternal = Type.GetType("System.Diagnostics.StackTrace, mscorlib").GetMethod("GetStackFramesInternal", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);


    var method = new DynamicMethod("GetStackTraceFast", typeof(object), new Type[0], typeof(StackTrace), true);

    var generator = method.GetILGenerator();
    generator.DeclareLocal(stackFrameHelperType);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, stackFrameHelperType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(bool), typeof(Thread) }));
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, GetStackFramesInternal);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    getTheStackTrace = (Func<object>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>));
}
```

How can I get the names of the methods from the call to `getTheStackTrace.Invoke()` I'm a little confused on how to get the information. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio Performance Profiling is not helping in that?

Comment: *I know that the StackTrace is not great for performance*: 1. Have you done any benchmarking on this? 2. Is this area the bottleneck? 3. What are your performance goals?

Comment: Note even if you can get what you have there to work you're using internal private methods. MS could rename or remove them at any time without warning

Comment: Some points to consider:

1) It uses reflection and dynamic method building, so you can't rely on the internal functions existing on all .NET platforms or not being able to use the Emit* methods(i.e. iOS).

2) All forms of tracing the stack are generally expensive. They're diagnostic tools after all.

I would suggest redesigning whatever it is you're building to use another form of tracking that doesn't depend on tracing the stack or using internal methods.

Comment: @KobyDuck Those are some really good points. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 2):

On modern versions of .Net (6.0 + Framework 4.7.2), I could not find the performance issues mentioned [in the article](https://ayende.com/blog/3879/reducing-the-cost-of-getting-a-stack-trace). I tried to set up the reflection recommended by [@SledgeHammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312589/1603383) and perform a benchmark. I could not detect either slow enough performance with [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace) or a significant improvement with the reflection approach to justify using reflection in modern applications.

| Method | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StackTrace | .NET 6.0 | 9.064 us | 0.0567 us | 0.0443 us |
| StackTrace | .NET Framework 4.7.2 | 10.701 us | 0.1510 us | 0.1339 us |
| Reflection | .NET 6.0 | 7.474 us | 0.0692 us | 0.0648 us |
| Reflection | .NET Framework 4.7.2 | 7.947 us | 0.1514 us | 0.1744 us |

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace MyBenchmarks
{
  [SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net472, baseline: true)]
  [SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
  public class StackTraceBenchmark
  {
    private static Func<int, IEnumerable<MethodBase>> _lambda = Create();

    public StackTraceBenchmark()
    {
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void StackTrace() => MethodA(false);

    [Benchmark]
    public void Reflection() => MethodA(true);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void MethodA(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodB(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodB(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodC(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodC(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodD(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodD(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodE(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodE(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodF(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodF(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodG(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodG(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodH(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodH(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodI(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodI(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodJ(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodJ(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodK(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodK(bool newMethod)
    {
      MethodZZZ(newMethod);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void MethodZZZ(bool newMethod)
    {
      if (newMethod)
      {
        var result = _lambda(0).Take(5).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
        var stack = new StackTrace(false);
        var result = Enumerable.Range(0, stack.FrameCount)
          .Select(i => stack.GetFrame(i).GetMethod())
          .Take(5)
          .ToList();
      }
    }

    private static Func<int, IEnumerable<MethodBase>> Create()
    {
      var stackFrameHelperType = typeof(StackTrace).Assembly.GetType("System.Diagnostics.StackFrameHelper");
      var getStackFramesInternal = typeof(StackTrace).GetMethod("GetStackFramesInternal", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
      var rangeMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Range");
      var stackFrameHelperCount = stackFrameHelperType.GetMethod("GetNumberOfFrames");
      var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Select").First()
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int), typeof(MethodBase));
      var getMethodBase = stackFrameHelperType.GetMethod("GetMethodBase");

      var skip = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "skip");
      var stackFrameHelperVar = Expression.Parameter(stackFrameHelperType, "stackFrameHelper");

      var iParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
      var selectLambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Call(stackFrameHelperVar, getMethodBase, iParam), iParam);

      var block = Expression.Block(new[] { stackFrameHelperVar }
        , Expression.Assign(stackFrameHelperVar, Expression.New(stackFrameHelperType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Thread) })
          , Expression.Constant(Thread.CurrentThread)))
        , Expression.Call(getStackFramesInternal, stackFrameHelperVar, skip, Expression.Constant(false), Expression.Constant(null, typeof(Exception)))
        , Expression.Call(selectMethod
          , Expression.Call(rangeMethod
            , skip
            , Expression.Subtract(Expression.Call(stackFrameHelperVar, stackFrameHelperCount), skip)
          )
          , selectLambda
        )
      );
      return Expression.Lambda<Func<int, IEnumerable<MethodBase>>>(block, skip).Compile();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually built something similar around the StackFrameHelper class as that example shows. Except I used cached / compiled expression trees to call the functions rather then IL since you need to call about 5 or 6 methods and everything is internal / private. Can't post the class due to copyright, but I can at least point you in the right direction. You need to new up an instance of StackFrameHelper, then call GetStackFramesInternal, then GetNumberOfFrames, then for each frame, you call GetMethodBase and you can call GetFileName and GetLineNumber if you need that info.

All of those methods are on the StackFrameHelper class except for GetStackFramesInternal which is on the StackFrame class.

That code you have above just goes to the GetStackFramesInternal level, which populates the StackFrameHelper instance.

Comment: @SledgeHammer thanks for the suggestion. I've never worked with expression trees so I thought I'd give it a try but was unable to make it work. I can get the instance of `StackFrameHelper` using `Expression.New` but from there on I was not able to make method calls. Any chance you could possibly post an example?